# WPF ListView selected item problem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, select

I have a ListView control with TextBox and Button inside the ListViewItem, my problem is that when you enter into a textbox the row doesn't select. If you want to select a row you have to click somewhere in the row where there is no control.

How can I make the row automaticly select when I click or enter into a child control of a row ?

I tried this on the button click event, but without any luck :

```
        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)sender;
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is ListViewItem))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep != null)
        {
            lvRoutes.SelectedItem = (ListViewItem)dep;
        }
```

It always keep the first row selected.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try using attached properties

```
public static class ItemSelector
{
    public static DependencyProperty MakeSelectionProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MakeSelection", 
        typeof(bool?), 
        typeof(ItemSelector), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMakeSelectionPropertyChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty ItemsControlProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemsControl", 
        typeof(ItemsControl), 
        typeof(ItemSelector));

    public static void SetMakeSelection(
        DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MakeSelectionProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetItemsControl(
        DependencyObject d, ItemsControl value)
    {
        d.SetValue(ItemsControlProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnMakeSelectionPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsControl = d.GetValue(ItemsControlProperty) 
            as ItemsControl;
        if (itemsControl == null)
            return;
        ((ListBoxItem) itemsControl.ContainerFromElement(d))
            .IsSelected = true;
    }
```

and heres its use

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}" 
             w:ItemSelector.MakeSelection="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsFocused}" 
             w:ItemSelector.ItemsControl="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=
                    {x:Type ListView}}}" Margin="10" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```